# Косвенная адресация Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, переменные

Помогите, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему нельзя присвоить значение переменной `mem3` таким образом?

```
mem3      DW    0
mov  mem3,[bx]
```

Comment: Это вопрос к компании Intel, а не к нам. Инструкция `MOV` у интеловских процессоров таки-да не умеет писать из памяти в память, одним из операндов должен быть регистр. Почему так — мы не знаем.

Comment: Добавлю, что по сути после подстановки конкретного адреса эта команда выглядела бы как `mov [число], [bx]`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инструкция `MOV` в интеловской архитектуре не умеет копировать данные между памятью и памятью. Либо источником, либо приёмником данных должен быть регистр.

Ваша гипотетическая инструкция хочет копировать данные из памяти, лежащей по адресу `BX`, в память `mem3`. Поскольку процессор этого не умеет, ассемблер отказывается компилировать такое.

Делайте копирование через регистр:

```
mov  ax, [bx]
mov  mem3, ax
```

Альтернативная конструкция с `MOVSW` устарела и слишком медленна на сегодняшних машинах. Ещё одна альтернативная конструкция с `PUSH`/`POP` плоха тем, что делает лишний промежуточный доступ к *памяти* (стеку).

---

**Обновление**: [Обсуждение на en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957622/276994) ссылается на то, что *память* работает либо на чтение, либо на запись. Таким образом, для копирования из памяти в память всё равно нужно сначала прочитать значение во временное хранилище, а затем записать его по новому адресу. Для временного хранилища и нужен промежуточный регистр. Инструкция `MOV` задумана как быстрая, поэтому она не делает ничего особенного «под капотом».

Comment: MOVSW устарела? А как насчет MOVSD? Я к тому, что не устарела, а используется в основном в связке с префиксом REP для копирования целого блока памяти.

Comment: @insolor: Насколько я понимаю, все «строковые» инструкции устарели. Например, [здесь](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf), раздел 16.10.

Comment: Почитал, вывод: с оговорками, типа копирование большого блока выровненных (желательно под 8 байт) данных, и там где важен размер кода, rep movsd использовать можно.

Comment: @insolor: Ну да, маленький размер кода. Но это по идее преимущество скорее под старые машины, на современных вряд ли маленький размер кода релевантен. Впрочем, под современные десктопные машины редко кто пишет на ассемблере, так что оговорка имеет смысл.

Comment: Есть специфичные случаи: к примеру, локализация, когда короткая STL-строка изначально инициализируется с помощью нескольких команд mov, а нужно эту строку инициализировать другой строкой произвольной длины. Больше мувов на старое место не воткнешь, поэтому либо вставляется rep movsd, либо, если для этого кода не хватает места (старая строка была очень короткая), код выносится в отдельную область в виде процедуры. Вот вам реальный пример для первого случая: http://i.imgur.com/EZ32JK4.png (стрелка к нашему случаю не относится)

Comment: @insolor: Понял, спасибо. Да, в определённых условиях может быть полезно.